# cloudinary upload file cannot find file

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, multer, cloudinary

I want to upload a file using cloudinary but it's not working. What it the file string parameter should be?

```
@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    id: string,
  ): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      v2.uploader.upload(
        file.filename,
        { public_id: id, folder: 'business', resource_type: 'auto' },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          resolve(result);
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the file object

```
{
  fieldname: 'DirectorsDetails',
  originalname: 'Eddy - Information about directors.xlsx',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  buffer: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 14 2a be 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 78 6c 2f 64 72 61 77 69 6e 67 73 2f 64 72 61 77 69 6e 67 31 ... 5072 more bytes>,
  size: 5122
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this see if it helps:

**Tune the multer to use memory storage for getting buffer in later stage**

```js
// app.module.ts
import { MulterModule } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { memoryStorage } from 'multer';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    MulterModule.register({
      storage: memoryStorage(), // use memory storage for having the buffer
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Turning buffer to stream and bootstrap it to upload**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadApiErrorResponse, UploadApiResponse, v2 } from 'cloudinary';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(
    file: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream((error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      });
      Readable.from(file.buffer).pipe(upload); // covert buffer to readable stream and pass to upload
    });
  }
}
```

---

If you want to save it to local directory first, you can do it but you will need to read the file from path via `fs.createReadStream` to make a stream of it and upload it to cloudinary.

---

If you cannot make it works, I can upload a example to github for you to cross-check.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `upload_stream` function.

```
import { FileUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(
    file: FileUpload,
  ): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream((error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      });

      file.createReadStream().pipe(upload);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It says `Property 'createReadStream' does not exist on type 'File'`

Comment: I've updated the answer with the type I use.

Comment: Still same `file.createReadStream is not a function`

Comment: I added the file object to the question

Answer (score 0):

`file.filename` is only populated if you store multer files on disk. Perhaps `file.originalname` is the property you're looking for.

Comment: even with that it says `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open filename`